# Vim: Aligning text to columns

Tags: vim

Let's say I have the following text:

```
key:value1 key:value234 key:val0
key:val1 key:value1 key:value5
key:value65799 key:value356 key:3790
```

Is it possible somehow to transform it to some kind of aligned columns?

```
key:value1          key:value234            key:val0
key:val1            key:value1              key:value5
key:value65799      key:value356            key:3790
```

Of course, I can replace separating spaces with tabs but that alone doesn't help...

Comment: try `:%s/ /\r/g` and then `:%!pr -3at`

Comment: @Sundeep interesting, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would normally first convert spaces to #, then use Align to align based on #, then remove #.

```
:%s/\ /#/g
:'<,'>Align#
:%s/\ /#/g
```

And the result is as follows.

```
key:value1      key:value234  key:val0
key:val1        key:value1    key:value5
key:value65799  key:value356  key:3790
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the job :).

Comment: you are welcome! btw there is an advanced plugin called easyalign, you may like it. though i am happy with simple Align command :)

Answer (score 6):

On a Unix-like system:

```
:%!column -t
```

Answer (score 2):

And if you dont mind using plugins see [tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular).

Here you can visually select your lines and use:

```
:'<,'>Tabular/ /
```

There's also [vim-easy-align](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align).

Comment: Probably best to use a pattern with `:Tabularize`, e.g. `:Tabularize/ /`

Comment: @PeterRincker in this case it would work but yes in general using a pattern is better.

Comment: Thanks, @PeterRincker!

Answer (score 1):

A regex based solution is as follow:

`:%s/\s/                  /g` followed by:

`:%s/\([^,]\{20}\)\(\s\+\)/\1/g`

Best regards.

Comment: it does not work on my vim. could you pls explain a bit on the second command?

Comment: Ok, the second command just group 2 things: first each 20 characters followed by nth spaces... then it keeps first part at replacement.